# Disable root in linux for SSH

Tags: linux, root

I currently have about 4 servers and I have always used root to login into SSH. But now I realize that its a security risk so what can I do to not login via root?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Then uncomment or add the following:

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

Then restart `sshd`:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

Answer (score 6):

Look into `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and set `PermitRootLogin` to `no`. Then restart sshd.

If you want to do administrative tasks through ssh, you can still use `su` (using roots password) or `sudo` (that has to be permitted in `/etc/sudoers` and you don't need the root password) to become root.

If you want your ssh deamon to be even more protected, you can login using public-key authentication. In that case, deactivate logins using passwords by setting `PasswordAuthentication` to `no`. Then you'll need keyfiles to login.

Comment: Public key authentication is highly recommended.

Comment: You may want "without-password" or "forced-commands-only" instead of "no". for "PermitRootLogin".  These options allow logins only using SSH public keys, or only keys that have a specific command set (for things like remote jobs that need to run as root, say backups).

Answer (score 2):

Make a separate account and use `sudo` instead...

Answer (score 0):

You can disable root logon in ssh_config in etc directory.
If you are asking from client side, login on other username.